# AngularJs two-way-data-binding not working for custome directive input elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created the custome directive for creating dynamic form elements based on backend data .I have created directive and template .Please find below my directive ,template and json string

```
angular.module('publicApp').directive('buildInput', function() {
   return {
       require: "ngModel",
       restrict:"E",
       scope:{
        build:"=", 
      },
       templateUrl:"views/directives/buildInput.html",

   }
  });
```

My template is

```
<label>{{build.reg_label}} 
    <span class="color-red">*</span>
</label>

<div ng-if="build.reg_type=='text'">
 <input class="form-control" type="text" required="true" ng-model="buildData[build.id]">
</div>
<div ng-if="build.reg_type=='select'">
<select ng-options="reg_option.value as reg_option.label for reg_option in build.reg_options" ng-model="buildData[build.id]">
    <option  value="" ng-show="$first">-- {{build.reg_label}} --</option>
 </select>
</div
```

>

view file is

```
 <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="build in builds">
                <build-input build="build" ></build-input>
   </div>
```

My json string is

```
[
{
    "id":"1",  
    "reg_label":"What is Your Name",
    "reg_type":"text",
},
{
    "id":"2",    
    "reg_label":"Select Gender",
    "reg_options":[
        {
            "label":"Male",
            "value":"M"
        },
        {
            "label":"Female",
            "value":"F"
        }
    ],
    "reg_type":"select",
}
```

]

why my modal not binding with scope variable buildData ?

Comment: What's `buildData` ? Is that something on the scope?

Comment: Where is `buildData` defined? I'm guessing in the outer scope? Then this should also be passed through to the directive via isolate scope with `"="`

Comment: Hi Omri Aharon i have difined in my controller scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your directive only knows `build` variable since your (isolated) scope is defined like this:

```
 scope:{
        build:"=", 
      },
```

Sounds like your `buildData` variable is defined on the controller where `builds` is defined, so you should extend your scope to look like:

```
scope:{
            build:"=", 
            buildData:"="
          },
```

And your HTML directive declaration:

```
<build-input build="build" build-data="buildData" ></build-input>
```

Comment: @MuraliYarra Could you please show where `buildData` is defined and what is looks like ?

Comment: @MuraliYarra I had a typo in the HTML. it should be `build-data="buildData"` and not `buildData="buildData"`. I updated my answer, could you please try again?

Comment: @MuraliYarra Great! Please try to accept answers/upvote them so that others coming to this post will know if you found any of them helpful.

Comment: @MuraliYarra Thanks, but I'm talking about the "check" sign to the left of my answer, please click it. There's also a vote counter there where you can use to upvote/downvote answers.